# PHP preg_split with \t

Tags: php

I have text file that contains:

```
Query1  gi|1786181|gb|AE000111|ECAE000111
```

And PHP file:

```
@ $fpout3=fopen("$dataPath/$jobid.out.par", "r");
while(!feof($fpout3)) {
$row = fgets($fpout3);
$element = preg_split("/\t/", $row);
$query = $element[0];
echo"query:";echo $query;echo"-";
$queryName = $element[1];
echo"queryname:";echo $queryName;echo"-";
}
```

The output is:

```
query:Query1-queryname:gi
```

Why the rest of queryname does not printed?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried doing a `print_r($element)` or `var_dump($element)` to see what the whole array looks like. Also, try examining `$row` to confirm that it does actually contain what you think it contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my problem.
I try to split responseText by "|".

```
var r= xhttp.responseText.split("|");
```

So when PHP find "|" character in the text file, it does not show the rest of the file. I change the character by another one "^".

```
var r= xhttp.responseText.split("^");
```

Thanks.